# Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File - Xcode 10.1 & iOS 10.0

Tags: ios, facebook

My app binary disappaearing from iTunes connect saying '***The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data***'

First of all, I am not using Bluetooth services anywhere in my app. Then I learnt that facebook SDK might be using Bluetooth services and so, I included the '*NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription*' entity in Facebook frameworks info.plist files along with my app's info.plist file .

This is my pod file for the project:

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'

pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Firebase/Core', '4.0.4'
pod 'Firebase/Database', '4.0.4'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '4.0.4'
pod 'FirebaseInstanceID', '2.0.0'

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKPlacesKit'
pod 'FBSDKMessengerShareKit'

pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView'
pod 'Toast-Swift', '~> 3.0.1'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'
pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
pod 'SideMenu'
pod 'InteractiveSideMenu'
pod 'SwiftSoup'
```

I've uploaded my build almost 30 times till now trying different things but still stuck in the same issue. Any help will be highlt appreciated.

EDIT:

Adding the screenshot of email from Apple.

[image]

Comment: Can you list all the pods that you are using?

Comment: Hey ! Please find the edited question!

Comment: Can you put the screenshot of Xcode showing capabilities of your app?

Comment: Only Push Notifications is On. Rest all are turned off (that's the default setting I think!)

Comment: What description(Value) you added with the key NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription?

Comment: [App Name] would like to make data available to nearby bluetooth devices even when you're not using the app!

Comment: Are you sure you are mentioning it in the correct plist and yur app do not have multiple plist?

Comment: No Multiple plists. I think it's the problem with description. I am no where using bluetooth in my app. I am not sure wha to put as description. Can you suggest any?

Comment: If you are not using bluetooth in your application, then try to find if you have mention ed core bluetooth framework in the app anywhere. if Yes remove it and remove this key also

Comment: We can't get to know which framework is using the bluetooth thing. Some online sources said facebook is using it and I can't remove facebook SDK!

Comment: Please add error screenshot if possible

Comment: Done! Added the screenshot of mail from Apple!

Comment: Have a look on this [link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62229#176847)  if it can answer your question. Though you may end up adding an `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` into your info.plist

Answer (score 0):

```
'FBSDKPlacesKit'
```

is the culprit.

```
The Places Kit abstracts-away most of the work of constructing these requests by handling location querying, and Wi-Fi and Bluetooth scanning, as well as structuring the query parameters.
```

refer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/ios

solution:
add your purpose to info.plist

Note: in my case, i was implementing Facebook Analytics, and the official doc of facebook directed to add the FBSDKPlacesKit, and it was unnecessary for the analytics.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with photo permission, I add two lines in my p list file, one for key and other for description why you need this permission.

you can change description as per you app requiremnt.

NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription
Bluetooth is required for Connectivity.